# Cannot GET /visitor/display-HomePage page when route in heroku mern project

Tags: heroku, project, mern

Whenever i run my mern project in heroku its work but when i route 2 -3 page their is this type of error occure.

```
Cannot GET /visitor/display-HomePage
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll see the message Cannot GET / if you don't specify which page it is that you're trying to get.

Did you try seeing the URL path? You might have entered a different page name like instead of http://localhost:3000/visitor/display-HomePage, you might have entered something different.